# Is it better to create one single hub for all messages, or different hubs for a specific range of messages?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

For example, I have a order assigning system. And different types of orders need to be sent to different clients. So should I define one single hub to handle all types of orders, or one hub for one type of order? The messages of different type of order could be different too.

Actually if I use only one hub, will different types of messages coming from different services/threads be sent sequentially in one thread or simultaneously in multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870059/best-use-of-signalr-hub/55873676?noredirect=1#comment98408524_55873676). Officially, no performance difference in having more than one hub. Link to the documentation is there also.

Comment: Is it possible to know for sure that if SignalR sends client messages in one thread or multiple? If I have one centralized SignalR api with multiple hubs defined and multiple requests from other several services called the HubContext methods to send messages to clients that might intersect in these messages, would it be no different whether I designed to use one single hub or one hub for one type of service?

Comment: As stated in the link to the docs, all hubs get the same http request information. So if you have 2 hubs, both get the same request and go from there. If you are concerned about performance regarding volume of requests, check the performance section of the docs as you will need to tune IIS to make changes. But generally this is not needed since it can send at such a high rate (around 25 messages per second).

Comment: Well, my trigger of message sending doesn't come from one of the clients, but from a background hostedservice. That's why I wanted to know if, from the server side point of view, SignalR sends messages in one thread or each thread for each call.

Comment: I do something similar. I have a console application that gets my web server stats, sends that to the hub, the defined method then broadcasts that to a monitoring page. This way I can see all the vitals I need without logging onto the server. I use the same hub as I do for broadcasting other data to my clients.